# ObjectHotTracked Event in devexpress

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am new to devexpress tools and given task to go through the codes related `DevExpress.XtraCharts`

So I came across this event `ChartControl.ObjectHotTracked` Event.
When I see the documentation of this in devexpress tutorial its written
"Occurs before any chart element is hot-tracked at runtime. "

Which I really did not understand.
And I really don't know what does chart element is hot tracked what does this hot tracked means.

Does this refers something to chart related terminologies.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hot-tracking" is a quite simple thing in DevExpress charts terminology. It means that end-users are able **to highlight** and/or **to select** different chart elements at run-time via the mouse pointer or using different gestures in a touch-device. The following image demonstrates how a constant line and a single series are painted if highlighted by an end user using the mouse pointer:
[image: chart highlighting]

The Hot-Track/Highlight/Hit-Test feature is useful if, for example, it's required to show certain information when the mouse pointer hovers over specific chart elements. Using the [ObjectHotTracked](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_ObjectHotTrackedtopic) event you can handle the moment when the mouse pointer moved from one chart element to another and do something in this regard with using all the information given from this event-handler's arguments.